# Handle message return from calling stored procedure in try.. catch -- T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

I'm calling a legacy stored procedure within a `try..catch`. When the stored procedure returns a message to the user with the details of the error in simple language, my `try..catch` is unable to detect it.

The returned message from the legacy stored procedure is like:

> Error state: 1, Error severity: 16, Error number: 50000 Error line:
> 33, Error procedure: *LegacyStoredProcedure*
> Error message: Please take care of ....
> Rolling back transaction.

Is there a way to detect the returned message from the stored procedure?

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN Transaction
    .....
    EXEC *thelegacySP*
    .....
  COMMIT Transaction
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE
          @ErrorLine        int,
          @ErrorMessage     nvarchar(2048),
          @ErrorNumber      int,
          @ErrorProcedure   nvarchar(126),
          @ErrorSeverity    int,
          @ErrorState       int;
                      
    SELECT  @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
            @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
            @ErrorProcedure = '*MyNewSP*',
            @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
            @now = GETDATE()
    
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION    
    INSERT INTO Validation.Table
      VALUES(
            @ErrorProcedure
            ,@ErrorNumber
            ,@ErrorMessage
            ,@ErrorSeverity
            ,@ErrorState
            ,@ErrorLine
            ,@now
      )
END CATCH
```

Comment: How is that message being returned?

Comment: We need a [mre] because [this works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c275065eb8fa474cc4d6055d9ea59102)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement error handling is to use `THROW;` to re-raise the original error

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRAN;
    .....
    EXEC *thelegacySP*
    .....
  COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION    

    INSERT INTO Validation.Table (
            ErrorProcedure
            ,ErrorNumber
            ,ErrorMessage
            ,ErrorSeverity
            ,ErrorState
            ,ErrorLine
            ,Date)
    VALUES (ERROR_LINE(),
            ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            ERROR_NUMBER(),
            '*MyNewSP*',
            ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            ERROR_STATE(),
            GETDATE());
    
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Note that this code is only necessary if you want to log errors.

If you do not want to log errors then you should not use `TRY/CATCH` at all. You only need `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` to ensure automatic rollback

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;
    .....
EXEC *thelegacySP*
    .....
COMMIT;
```

You may find [Erland Sommarskog's articles](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) informative, if rather lengthy.

Comment: Hi Mate, I have 2 questions here: 1. Doesn't the INSERT statement in the CATCH block get ROLLBACK when there is an error - hence its never logged? 2. I am going through the nice article you have shared, and there the author says `For production-grade code it's not really sufficient to rely on XACT_ABORT, but for quick and simple stuff it can do.` - any reason you think he mentions this?

Comment: 1. Correct, the `ROLLBACK` should have been before the `INSERT`. 2. That's because he wants to log everything server-side. I personally believe server-side errors could be logged using XEvents if necessary, and client-side code will normally catch everything anyway